# equivalent of RubyGems?

Tags: go, rubygems

I come from a ruby background, and I just started learning go. Is there any standard way to install 3rd-party libraries that's comparable to RubyGems?

Comment: https://golang.org/pkg/

Comment: What you’re asking is actually for the equivalent of Bundler which handles resolving dependencies and installing gems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since go1.11 released, we have an official go package management tools, the [Go Modules](https://blog.golang.org/using-go-modules).

The difference between go modules and other package management tools is go modules does not rely on `$GOPATH`. The project must be placed outside of `$GOPATH`. If your project is already inside a `$GOPATH` but you wanted to use package management tools, then I suggest to see the old answer below.

Usage:

```golang
mkdir testproject
cd testproject

# init project as go module with root package name is testproject
go mod init testproject

# install 3rd party library, it will be stored inside testproject/vendor
go get github.com/labstack/echo
go get github.com/novalagung/gubrak
```

the `go mod init` command generates Go.mod file (similar like `Gemfile` for ruby). You can either install the 3rd party libraries through the usual `go get` command, or by adding the library metadata into `Go.mod` file then perform `go mod tidy`.

More informations about Go Modules: https://blog.golang.org/using-go-modules

## Old answer

Go does have package management tool as well, it's called [dep](https://github.com/tools/godep).

Usage example:

```
cd $GOPATH/src
mkdir testproject
cd testproject

# init project
dep init

# install 3rd party library
dep ensure -add github.com/labstack/echo
dep ensure -add github.com/novalagung/gubrak
```

dep generates [Gopkg.toml](https://golang.github.io/dep/docs/Gopkg.toml.html) file (similar like `Gemfile` for ruby). You can either install the 3rd party libraries through `dep ensure -add` command, or by adding the library metadata into `Gopkg.toml` then perform `dep ensure`.

Btw, there is also few other alternatives other than dep. For more information please take a look at https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/PackageManagementTools.